# Searching for a modern AGN Catalog

Tags: active-galaxy

I am searching for a simple, modern catalog of Active Galactic Nuclei. I expected a catalog similar to [this](http://www.frbcat.org/) or [this](https://sne.space/), but instead found that they contain observed spectra instead of properties like the mass, luminosity, SMBH mass, etc (take SDSS for example).

So, my question is, **Is there any modern catalog of AGN and their properties?**

Comment: is something like https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/full_html/2010/10/aa14188-10/aa14188-10.html#SECTION00030000000000000000 useful?  Catalogues tend to contain observable information, and this one has position, luminosity (in U, B  V bands) and redshift.  It doesn't have mass, because that can't be observed.

Comment: @James thanks for the link, though it was not what I was looking for. I didn't know that SMBH mass are not a part of the catalogs.